# Is it okay to modify some state in Redux if after we modify it we call an action to overwrite the old state?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

OK, say I have an initial state in our Redux store that looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
   userReports: [],
   activeReport: null,
}
```

userReports is a list of reports. activeReport is one of those reports (the one that is actively being worked with).

I want the active report to point to one in the array. In other words, if I modify the active report, it would modify one in the userReports array. This means, the two objects must point to the same memory space. That's easy to set up.

The alternative to this approach would be to copy one of the reports that is in the userReports array and set it as the active report (now it has a different memory address). The problem is now, when I edit the activeReport, I also have to search through the array of userReports, find the report that resembles the active report and modify it there too. This feels verbose.

**Here is the question:**

Would it be bad practice to have the activeReport point to a report in the array (same object). When I want to change the report I could do something like this (example is using redux thunk):

```
export const updateReport = (report) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
   try {
      const report = getState().reports.activeReport
      // modify the active report here
      report.title = "blah blah blah"
      dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_REPORT, payload: report })
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(`ERROR: ${error.message}`)
   }
}
```

And in my reducer:

```
case ACTIONS.UPDATE_REPORT:
     return { ...state, activeReport: action.payload }
```

as you can see, after updating the report I still return a "new version" of that report and set it as active, but this approach also updates the report in the userReports array because they point to the same memory address.

Answer (score 1):

I would say thats not ideal, do the reports have id's?  If they do I would rather hold the userReports in an object with keys being the id's, then active report can just be an id and renamed to activeReportId so you can fetch the activeReport with userReports[activeReportId]

You also asked for reasons:

So firstly any screen that looks at userReports wont rerender because the reports aren't being reassigned.

Secondly if someone later wants to update those screens they will reassign userReports which could cause problems.

Thirdly its an unusual pattern which is a huge no no for redux.  The point of redux is that it has a very obvious pattern so when you add things to it you don't have to think and can just make changes with confidence.

Comment: So how would I then modify the active report? Even if I look it up by accessing the activeReport ID and then finding it's corresponding report in the array, I would still have to modify the report directly in state, the only difference is instead of modifying it as the "activeReport" I now have to find it in the userReprorts first, still modify it there, and then update the state.

Comment: correct, 

action: type updateActiveReport, newReportData: {}

reducer:
case 'updateActiveReport': 
return {
...state,
userReports: { ...state.user.userReports, [state.activeReport]: newReportData}
}

Answer (score 0):

Your `activeReport` should not be pointing to an object in the `userReports` array, but rather it should be an `id` of the report, which the user is currently working on. Each of the report in the `userReports` will have a unique `id` field to identify the report - this would be helpful when rendering in react - this `id` field can be used as key.

Then your action creator/dispatcher will look like this:

```
export const updateReport = (updatedReport) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
   dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_REPORT, payload: updatedReport });
}
```

You will call this on change in your component:

```
const onTitleChangeHandler = (e) => { 
    var newTitle = e.target.value;
    // you will get the userReports and activeReport from props or by using some redux selector, also you will need to get dispatch and getState from redux
    var activeReportObj = userReports.filter((r) => r.id === activeReport)[0];
    updateReport({ title: newTitle, ...activeReportObj })(dispatch, getState);
}
```

Lastly, your reducer will be:

```
case ACTIONS.UPDATE_REPORT:
     var newUserReports = state.userReports.map((r) => { 
         if (r.id === state.activeReport) {
             return action.payload;
         }
         return r;
     });
     return { newUserReports, ...state };
```

Comment: I know how to do it the way you're suggesting.....My question was more about whether this other approach I want to try is a bad practice or not. And, if it is, why?